# How to use VentureCraft/revisionable in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, revisionable

I want know how to use [VentureCraft/revisionable](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable#display) in CRUD application and get a history

Ex : users every day need to add mileage and edit mileage ...... in my view (revision.blade.php) i want get history who has add and edit i tried but i don't know how to go next step ?

This is Model

```
class Mileage extends Model
{
    use \Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait;
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

This is Route

```
Route::get('/history', function () {
    $mileage = \App\Mileage::all();
    $history = $mileage->revisionHistory;
    return view('revision',compact('history'));
});
```

i don't know what code to use for view ????

mileage has user_id, date,mileage i want show like this

Ex : user ...A... has add mileage for .....date.... value is ...mileage...

if they edit i want show like this user ...A... has update mileage for .....date.... value is ...mileage... to ...mileage... how can i do this ?

Comment: Not working on Laravel 5.5 any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Before displaying the history. Firstly the revisionable library assumes that in your Mileage model the relationship method for the user model is called 
user() because the FK in the milage table is user_id. Also you need to add the following code to your User model and Mileage model.

```
public function identifiableName(){
    return $this->name;
}
```

On your view you need to loop through the history array like this.

```
@foreach($history as $h )
     <li>{{ $h->userResponsible()->first_name }} has updated milage  {{ $h->fieldName() }} from {{ $h->oldValue() }} to {{ $h->newValue() }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/history', function () {
    $mileage = \App\Mileage::all();
    return view('revision',compact('mileage'));
});
```

Now in your `blade` file

```
  @foreach($mileage->revisionHistory as $history )
    <p class="history">
      {{ $history->created_at->diffForHumans() }}, {{ $history->userResponsible()->name }} changed
      <strong>{{ $history->fieldName() }}</strong> from
      <code>{{ $history->oldValue() }}</code> to <code>{{ $history->newValue() }}</code>
    </p>
  @endforeach
```

Now if you need history in `controller` or in any other place you have to call `revisionHistory` of instances of `model` that uses `RevisionableTrait` trait